# Haskell: Are there other things like "_" that you can use to say that you don't care what the value is?

Tags: haskell, operators, ghci

So I wrote a hexapawn game and I'm trying to make a function that returns True if the board is in a winning state, it looks like this at the moment:

```
checkWin :: BoardState -> Bool
checkWin b1@(blackPieces,whitePieces,turn,size,win)
  |(length blackPieces) == 0 = True
  |(length whitePieces) == 0 = True
  |length (generateMoves b1) == 0 = True
  |otherwise = False
```

So this works if there are no black or white pieces left or if no one can make a move but it doesn't work if an opposing pawn reaches the end of the board(another way to win in hexapawn). The variables *blackPieces* and *whitePieces* are list of coordinates ie [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)] of where those pawns are on the board of *size* n (*turn* is true if its whites turn)

I was tempted to add these conditions to the method but the compiler didn't like it.

```
  |(_,1) `elem` whitePieces = True
  |(_,size) `elem` blackPieces = True
```

Is there any other way to say "Are there any tuples in *whitePieces* who's second element is a 1(i.e reached the other side of the board)."

Thanks in advance for your **helpful** comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So we want a function that receives a list of something `[a]`, a predicate over somethings `(a->Bool)` and returns a `Bool`. A quick check on [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5ba%5d+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+Bool) and we get back

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
Applied to a predicate and a list, any determines if any element of
the list satisfies the predicate. For the result to be False, the list must be finite
```

So

```
 (_,1) `elem` whitePieces
```

becomes

```
 any (\(_, x) -> x == 1) whitePieces
```

or (as eternalmatt reminds me)

```
any (==1) ( map snd whitePieces )
```

and so on

---

By the way, the best way to check is a list is empty is via pattern matching or the `null` function. The length == 0 method will walk through all of the linked list and might even enter an infinite loop if the list is infinite.

Comment: I like `any (==1) $ map snd whitePieces` but they are functionally the same.

Comment: Just for completeness's sake: `any ((== 1) . snd) whitePieces` is a third way of writing the same thing.

Comment: How about `1 \`elem\` map snd whitePieces`?

Answer (score 2):

you could for example use `filter`:

```
not $ null (filter wincond whitePieces)
    where wincond x = snd x == 1
```

this expression is `True` if the list of `whitePieces` with second entry `1` is not an empty list (`[]`)

or you could use `map`:

```
or (map (\x -> snd x == size) blackPieces)
```

this expression does: first it checks if an element of `blackPieces` has second entry equal to `size` and gives a list of `Trues` and `Falses` (`[Bool]`) then the function `or` gives `True` if any of them is `True`

Comment: note that `any f = or . map f` -- any is "orMap", all is "andMap".

Comment: cool did not know this - so +1 for your answer - as i cannot +1 comments

Answer (score 2):

The reason the compiler doesn't like that is because `_` only works on *pattern matches*. The underscore means "I *could* bind this portion of the data to a variable name, but I don't need to."

The way you tried to use it is different: you basically said "*does there exist* an `x` such that `(x,1)` is an element of `whitePieces`?"

Can you see the difference? See also [Haskell 2010 > Expressions # Patter Matching](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17)

Comment: Yah, I know why that doesn't work, I used it as an example so you could get an idea of what I was trying to do.